# git java wrapper - git pull never ends

Tags: java, git

I'm creating a simple Java wrapper for git executable, that I want to use in my app.
A small code example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String gitpath = "C:/eclipse/git/bin/git.exe";
        File folder = new File("C:/eclipse/teste/ssadasd");
        try {
            folder.mkdirs();
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                    gitpath + " clone git@192.168.2.15:test.git", null,
                    folder);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The code simply never ends the execution.. seems like it has caught inside `exec`. 
If I run the git clone via command line, it work as expected.
If I try another repository, from github, e.g., it works too.

Someone have a ide for what is going on here?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I know it doesn't fix your issue, but using JGit might be easier than creating a wrapper from scratch: http://eclipse.org/jgit/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, but you may want to take a look at [JGit](http://www.eclipse.org/jgit/), which is direct Java implementation of Git operations (no wrapping of commandline git). JGit gets a lot of use and stabilization work as it is the foundation for EGit (Eclipse Git integration).

Comment: i'll try it anyway... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12734760/jgit-how-to-add-all-files-to-staging-area

Answer (score 2):

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec` returns a [`Process`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) object that you can use to interact with the process and see what's going on. My suspicion is that you just need to do something like this:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
    gitpath + " clone git@192.168.2.15:test.git", null,
    folder);
p.waitFor();
```

If not, you can also do `getErrorStream()` or `getOutputStream()` on the process to see what it's writing out; that might be helpful in debugging.

Comment: it does not work.. get output stream only shows me `Cloning into 'test'...`

Answer (score 1):

`Runtime.exec()` can cause hanging under various circumstances - see [this article](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html?page=1) which quotes the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html), which says (in JDK 7):

> Because some native platforms only provide limited buffer size for standard input and output streams, failure to promptly write the input
>   stream or read the output stream of the subprocess may cause the
>   subprocess to block, and even deadlock.

The article gives some example solutions, which consume the output and error streams, although I think the ProcessBuilder class was introduced after the article was written, so may be more satisfactory: the newer Javadoc adds:

> Where desired, [subprocess I/O can also be redirected](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirect-input) using methods of the ProcessBuilder class.